# How to write data to an Android phone connected through USB from a C++ Windows Desktop Application

Tags: android, c++, windows, winapi, usb

I am trying to develop a system wherein I need to save data directly to an Android smartphone connected through USB from a Windows desktop app written in C++. Since I'm targeting old Windows versions such as XP, I want to make the application as stand-alone as possible, that's why I'm not using .NET.

I have searched Microsoft's docs and it doesn't seem to contain what I want. The closest that I've seen is [How to Access a USB Device by Using WinUSB Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device), but that still doesn't contain what I'm looking for.

So, given the absence of official docs, is it even possible?

Comment: It' not possible. Create an android app which will receive the data you want through TCP.

Comment: One way to communicate with an Android device over USB is via the [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb). It doesn't directly allow you to pass arbitrary data to the device, but it does allow you to share files, and create TCP connections to the device (amongst other things).